# UILabel render text incorrectly in IOS7

Tags: uilabel, ios7

I use following code to calculate the bound of a `UILabel`

```
CGRect bound = [lblName.text boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){206, 99999}
                                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                 attributes:stringAttributes
                                          context:nil];
```

The `UILabel` is a embedded in a `UIScrollView`, which is a subview of `UITableViewCell`.

here what i got

[image]

I made a test which use a `UILabel` in a table cell, and a `UILabel` in `UIScrollView` separately, and results are as I expected

[image]

Note that all setting (font, line break mode etc) of `UILabel` are the same in all those case. The `boundingRectWithSize` returns same result in all those case, only difference is the way `UILabel` render the text.

What is the problem here? did i miss sometthing?

**UPDATE**: this happen only when i load UILabel from nib, if it is created programmatically, there is no problem. (my project is migrated from xcode 4 to xcode 5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was seeing the same behavior with some of my labels, which looked fine in iOS 6, but in iOS 7 they had extra padding at the top and bottom as in your pictures.

Here's what I had to do to finally get it to layout correctly in `viewDidLoad` - works on both iOS 6 and 7.

```
self.someLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
self.someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(
    self.someLabel.frame.origin.x,
    self.someLabel.frame.origin.y,
    labelWidth, // define elsewhere if you're targeting different screen widths
    self.someLabel.bounds.size.height);
[self.someLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to set my labels position manually to suit iPhone 4 and 5 designs based on your explenation. I am using `self.myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` and `self.myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 280, 21);` but the position only shows the one in the storyboard and not the numbers I selected in the `CGRectMake`. If I change the text in the label it changes it, but the new position no. I am doing this in `viewDidLoad` and I am on Xcode 5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
bound.size.height += 1;
```

**UPDATE:**

According to Apple's document

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

> This method returns fractional sizes (in the size component of the returned CGRect); to use a returned size to size views, **you must use raise its value to the nearest higher integer using the ceil function.**

So you might want to use this approach:

```
bound.size.height = ceil(bound.size.height);
```

Comment: I believe this statement is true for all `boundingRectWithSize` methods (NSAttributedString in my case).